Android studioのエミュレーター上で、Firebase経由でアプリをインストールしたい
Android studio上でAndroidエミュレーター(pixel 3aなど)を起動し、
そのエミュレーター上で、Firebase経由でアプリをインストールしたいと考えています。
しかし、Firebase登録後に届くメールで「Get startedボタン」をクリックしても、真っ白な画面に遷移してしまい、アプリを取得できません。
※Get startedボタンは以下にリンクしています。
https://appdistribution.filebase.google.com/accept/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
画面が真っ白にならず、アプリをインストールするためにはどんな設定が必要でしょうか。
